# Como usar o IF ternário

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Como ficaria a seguinte situação utilizando *if ternário*?

```
if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) < 30 then
      Edit2.Text := '30'
   else if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) in [30..50] then
      Edit2.Text := '40'
   else
      Edit2.Text := '50'
```

Comment: As versões mais recentes receberam o operador ternário ou tu se refere a gambiarra do `IfThen`?

Comment: IfThen, apenas para conhecimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = StrToInt(Edit1.Text);

Edit2.Text = IfThen(v < 30, '30', IfThen(v in [30..50], '40', '50'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Em linguagens de programação, a expressão `:?`, é conhecido por ser um [Operador Ternário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), varias linguagens o adota, porém em até em sua última versão Seattle 10, o Delphi **não** adota.

Porém a partir do Delphi7, existe a opção de utilizar o `IfThen`:

```
IfThen([Expressão boleana], [Se verdadeiro], [Se falso])
```

Porém, você não pode fazer isso:

```
y:= IfThen(x <> 0, 1/x, 0);
```

Sendo necessário utilizar do jeito tradicional:

```
if x <> 0 then y := 1/x else y := 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

server por exemplo: intercalar linhas claras e escurar em um relatório.
IfThen(flag=true,flag:=false,flag:=true)